# How to change UITableViewHeader background color when tapped in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I want to change tapped UITableViewHeader when tapped in each view. I've wrote following coding but it does not work at all. Please help how to solve that issue.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 25)];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, tableView.frame.size.width, 25)];
    [label setFont:CHECKOUT_HEADER_FONT];
    label.textColor = GLOBAL_PRIMARY_COLOR;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [label setText:CategoryName];
    label.backgroundColor = GLOBAL_BACKGROUND;
    [view setBackgroundColor: GLOBAL_BACKGROUND];
    [view addSubview:label];

    view.tag = section;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *headerTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return view;
}


- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    // DOES NOT WORK
    UIView *header = [_productTableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    header.backgroundColor = GLOBAL_PRIMARY_COLOR;
}
```

Comment: You can use a button instead label and remove tap gesture .

Comment: If you want to change only background color then button is preferable otherwise for huge change in view you can go for tap gesture. But I doubt that tap gesture will work on header only , it can work on tableview as a whole in that case didSelect delegate function will not be called .

Comment: I want to change header view only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this viewForHeaderInSection

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 25)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    tempView.tag = section;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *headerTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [tempView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return tempView;
}
- (IBAction)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (recognizer.view.tag) {
        case 0:
            recognizer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```